# How can I remove a hot water timer installed by the property owner?

Tags: plumbing

My landlord has just installed a device that cuts hot water supply after 3 min of using hot water.

I open the hot water tap and after 3min then water out of the tap run out meaning Nothing comes out then after 12min there is hot water again and the cycle continues. There is nothing wrong with the cold water tap. There is no timer in the cold water only the hot water.

What is the device called that he used and how do we remove it.

Comment: This sounds more like a legal question, than a question for a do-it-yourself home improvement website.  If you don't own the property, modifying the plumbing would likely require permission from the property owner.

Comment: Find a new place to live, and have fun in small claims court if you want to get any compensation, your security deposit back, etc. - or take the guy to court while still living there for the violation of the lease; if, in fact, the lease provides any protection from this sort of BS, which it probably does not, explicitly, leaving you with whatever the local "implicit" expectation for hot water supply in a rental is. If you modify the plumbing you will definitely be legally in the wrong.

Comment: I would say this might be a legal question the other way around too, depending on the adopted codes.  If I was invited to inspect the property that has this in my city, I would fail it.  This would not supply *adequate* hot water supply for daily self-care, considering average shower time is 6-8 minutes in the US.  And I am fairly certain the municipal judge here would agree.

Comment: Circumvention of a device like this is illegal, and grounds for eviction even in a rent-control area where you would otherwise be protected.   Hence you will not get any help here.   However rent control areas usually don't allow the landlord to downgrade service, so try  legal.stackexchange.com

Comment: When you give the landlord a rent check tell them is only good for 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The device is probably something like a [hot water timer](http://www.showermanager.com/conservation-store/shower-timer-home.shtml) (but installed upstream, in the mechanical room), which comprises a timer mechanism and a shutoff or diverter valve.

As to how you'd disable it, you'd have to find out the model of the device. Chances are it can be disabled via its controls. Otherwise it would need to be removed and the pipe spliced.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that a timing device was installed? If your not it may be that there is a blockage on the hot water side. When the water is turned off, it seeps by the blockage and the pressure builds up so that when you turn the water on it appears to run out at full flow. After some time the pressure falls off.